# ionic 3 header request not sending in post method

Tags: http, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am developing an app for sending request of json data with header and alse receive response of json data with header.
The receiving of response is working correctly But in request sending header is not sending. when adding header the response showing error.
 when i am using

```
let header = new HttpHeaders();
header = header.set('abc', '22');
alert(header.get('abc'));

    this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/login', {postParams}, {header}).then(data => {
        console.log(data.status);
        console.log(data.data); // data received by server
        console.log(data.headers);
    var json = JSON.stringify(data.headers);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.headers["x-auth-token"]));

})
.catch(error => {

    console.log(error.status); // showing as "undefined"
    console.log(error.error); // showing as "undefined"
    console.log(error.headers); // showing as "undefined"
});
```

when using this code it showing "undefined" in error section

but it working without header

```
this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/login', {postParams}, {header}).then(data => {
```

The response also getting header.

I am using HTTP. 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

The full code is shown below.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
import { RestProvider } from '../providers/rest/rest';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage
],
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    HTTP,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    RestProvider
]
})
export class AppModule {}

**rest.ts**

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions  } from '@angular/http';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {

    apiUrl = 'http://192.168.0.11:5005/ksjp/api';
constructor(private http: HTTP) {
    console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
}

getPost(data) {     
    return new Promise(resolve => {
let header = new HttpHeaders();
header = header.set('abc', '22');
console.log(header.get('abc'));  // display the value '22'

    let postParams = data;
        this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/login', {postParams}, {header})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);
    var json = JSON.stringify(data.headers);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);
});

});

}

}
```

I have tried different method but no use . please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue.

You can try adding header like below:

```
    let headers = {
      "Content-type": 'application/xml',
      "Authorization": token,
    };
```

and add header object like this

```
this.http.post(url, xmlBody, headers).then((response) => {}
```

By doing this your header will send with your request.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: any issue or error are you facing ? bcus as per code I think it should work.

Comment: That code not working. but i put header directly. the answer i have posted.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer when adding the header directly in the request.

```
 this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/login', {postParams}, {"Content-Type": "application/json","auth":"anbnvbnhvbnbnvbnvbnbnbn"})
```

This one is working for me